# What is the reason to use GeoServer to provide access to vector data?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, web-mapping, web-service, web

I am building a website that will present spatial data (Leaflet) and I plan to include functionalities like: add, move, delete features (i.e. by clicking on the map or on the feature) I would like to use PostGIS as DB.

Should I use a GeoServer and if so why?

I was planning to store vector data and request them as GeoJSON from DB. The approximate amount of records (10 000 - 100 000).

Comment: If you use a standard interface, you open up the possibility of other clients being able to access your data

Comment: related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77246/editing-vector-data-over-the-net-wfs-or-postgis

Comment: and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77656/advantages-of-wfs-over-geojson-kml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoServer is a very full-featured geospatial web service solution.  But if all you want is to serve GeoJSON from PostGIS, there are other options which might be simpler to deploy, manage, configure and secure.

For instance, the Crunchy Data [pg-featureserv](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_featureserv) server implements the new OGC API for Features protocol (aka WFS3), which is based on modern web standards (such as is REST, OpenAPI, and GeoJSON).  It has some nice features such as ability to serve layers defined by Postgres/PostGIS functions.  It provides "DB-only" configuration, and is 100% focussed on serving PostGIS spatial data.